# WebElement is identified through xpath in the developer console but the element wont be identified through selenium findElement method

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

The html element Im trying to locate is the "Shared" link.

[image]

I wrote a dynamic xpath to locate the element and it shows as the element was identified in the developer console.

[image]

But when i use the xpath that i wrote in the developer console to locate the element using selenium, it does not locate the element.
The method i used to check if it locates the element is shown below.

[image]

I could not figure out why this issue occurs, Is it because of a issue in the xpath that i have written or because of another issue?

Comment: Link is probably dynamic. Try to implement Implicit/Explicit wait

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, it started identifying the element. But still Im not able to use methods like click on the element, do you have any clue why that happens?

Comment: Try to use following xpath:driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='quickshare-indicator enabled'][@title='This document is shared (click for more options)']"));

Comment: The element is identified, but still selenium is not able to click on the link

Comment: It started working after i used an implicit wait of 5 seconds and used the xpath that can be copied through the developer console.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you can try out is :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(" your Xpath ")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your Xpath")).click();
```

The Xpath you have written would work if only one title is present on current page.

Comment: Add please share text instead of pics , so we can help with the exact solution.

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow, I'll make sure that I practice that in the future, thanks for the advice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

driver.find_elements doesn't have attribute to click() so use driver.findElement instead of Elements

Comment: Yes, I used driver.findElements to check if the element gets identified. The problem got solved after I used an implicit wait and used the xpath that can be copied through the developer console.